# ValueError: "<Notification: Notification object>" needs to have a value for field "notification" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Notification(BaseTimestampableModel):
# TYPES CONSTANTS HERE
# TYPE_CHOICES DICT HERE

    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender_notifications')
    receivers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='receiver_notifications')
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    data = models.TextField()
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = _('Notification')
       verbose_name_plural = _('Notifications')


    def send(self):
        # Logic for sending notification here

        self.sent = True
        self.save()
```

For other hand, I've this "static" class:

```
class ChatNotifications:
    @staticmethod
    def message_created(message, chat):
        """
        Send a notification when a chat message is created
        to all users in chat except to the message's sender.
        """
        sender = message.user

        data = {
            'text': message.text,
            'phone': str(sender.phone_prefix) + str(sender.phone),
            'chatid': chat.uuid.hex,
            'time': timezone.now().timestamp(),
            'type': 'text',
            'msgid': message.uuid.hex
        }
        notification = Notification(
            sender=sender,
            receivers=chat.get_other_users(sender),
            type=Notification.TYPE_CHAT_MESSAGE,
            data=json.dumps(data)
        )
        notification.send()
```

But when I call ChatNotifications.message_created(msg, chat) (message and chat are previusly saved), I get this error:

```
ValueError: "<Notification: Notification object>" needs to have a value for field "notification" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Researching on Google, I try do [this](http://guido.vonrudorff.de/django-manytomany-relationship-and-unsaved-objects/), but this don't solved my problem.

With debug, I checked the error is throwing when Model constructor is called.

This is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/vagrant/petycash/apps/chats/notifications.py", line 45, in message_created
data=json.dumps(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 550, in __init__
setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 499, in __set__
manager = self.__get__(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 476, in __get__
return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 783, in __init__
(instance, self.source_field_name))
ValueError: "<Notification: Notification object>" needs to have a value for field "notification" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t associate `Notification` with a `User` until it’s been saved.

So you have to save `Notification` first then you can add `receivers`

```
notification = Notification(
    sender=sender,
    type=Notification.TYPE_CHAT_MESSAGE,
    data=json.dumps(data)
).save()
# If chat.get_other_users(sender) return a queryset
receivers = chat.get_other_users(sender)
for receiver in receivers:
    notification.receivers.add(receiver)
# or you can also simply assign the whole list as it's already empty after new create
# >>> notification.receivers = recievers
notification.send()
```

Comment: This solved this problem, but now, I get TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable. 

The code of get_other_users(user) method is: return self.users.exclude(pk=user.pk)

Comment: if `self.users.exclude(pk=user.pk)` return a list of users you can loop over this list and add each user to `notification` object . `for user in chat.get_other_users(sender):`   `notification.receivers.add(user)`

Comment: [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) return a queryset, and if I'm not mistaken, this is a tuple.

Comment: `for other_user in chat.get_other_users(sender):` `notification.receivers.add(other_user)` occurs the same error.

Comment: Sorry, this works propertly, the problem is throwing when I acces in send method. The line is `APNSDevice.objects.filter(user__in=self.receivers)`. I solved it using `APNSDevice.objects.filter(user__in=self.receivers.all())`